# Separating any character in string with Java

Tags: java, string

Here is my input:

> my in-1@123pu*(46t789

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "my in-1@123pu*(456t789";
    String[] words = input.split("(\\s+|(?:(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])))");
    String output = "";
    for (String s : words) {
        output += s+" ";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

The code execution output is:

> my in-1@123 pu*(456 t 789

How to get output like this:

> my in - 1 @ 123 pu * ( 456 t 789

I need add a separator (e.g. space) between special characters and numbers.

Comment: It would be nice if you also provide a list of characters that you treat as `special` chars (it's clear that those are @ - *, but probably you have more).

Comment: I'm personally not a RegEx fan, so I'd solve this by hand. Ignore me if you're looking for a RegEx answer. I'd create an array of Strings, each entry (=String) being all characters of one of the sets you intend to keep as a group. I'd use a loop to check if array[i].indexOf(currentCharacter)>=0, record the array index that has a hit (if any) and see if the previous character was in the same group. I'd use a StringBuilder (that can be reused per word via sb.setLength(0)) to build the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one

```
String[] ww = input.split("\\s+" +             // consume white space
     "|(?:" +                                  // start non-capture
         "(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9 ])" +                // look behind non alphanumeric & white space
         "|(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9 ])" +                // look ahead non alphanumeric & white space
         "|((?=[0-9])(?<![0-9 ]))" +           // ahead is number, behind is letter 
         "|((?=[a-zA-Z])(?<![a-zA-Z ]))" +     // ahead is letter, behind is number
     ")");
```

Result:

```
my in - 1 @ 123 pu * ( 456 t 789
```